# In excel, how can I automate a sheet to be filled based on conditions of another sheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Is there a way in excel to copy the contents of one column to another sheet based on particular values in another column.

I have data which looks like this:

Sheet1:
[image]

Sheet2:

[image: enter code here]

I would like to copy the column A of sheet 1 directly onto column A of sheet 2, but only if the value in column B is Y.

I have tried used the match function but am not sure how the best way to do this would be. Is there a way for me to achieve this?

My desired output is:

[image: sheet 3 showing sheets 1 and 2 merged based on column values in sheet 1]

Comment: Your merged sheet 3 appears to me to not be filtered by the employed category (i.e. x.1.c is still there, despite column B having an n). Is this intended to be removed in sheet 3?

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! (Sorry didn't notice on my first comment) I have a few follow-up questions: if it is intended to be filtered, how do you want sheet 2 to behave? Do you intend it to be a one-time merge, or to have it update automatically as values change on sheet 1? What about the columns for date and type on sheet 2? Are you going to be putting static values in those columns?

Comment: @Chronicide i intend to have sheet 2 automatically change as values in sheet 1 are changed. Thank you for spotting that in my desired column x.1.c is still there, that was an error and it shouldn't have been there. I will be putting static values in the other columns manually.

Comment: @Waldof99 Thanks for answering my questions. An issue that I can see with your proposed workflow is that you would be mixing dynamic values with static. For example, what would happen to sheet 2 when you change a Y to an N when someone leaves? Sheet 2 would remove the row from columns A and B, and leave the static values in place. A and B would shift up, and become un-synced from the values in C and D. I think that a possible solution would be to have one sheet with all static values, and to turn on filters. Then you can filter to show only those rows with a Y in column B. Would this work?

Comment: @Chronicide Thank you very much for your comment. I can see why it would present an issue. In this dataset the values in sheet one wouldn't change from Y/N, but they may be blank and then have Y or N inputed. Would this also cause the sheets to be unsynced? Please can you give examples on how i can place the filter in my spreadsheet as i'm new to excel. Thank you

Comment: I've added some instructions on tables and filters in my answer below. One last thing I wanted to mention is that your screenshots show your real name in the top right (This happens when you have signed in to a Microsoft account, or if the company you work for integrates Office with their Active Directory). No worries if you don't mind having your real name shown, but I figured I'd point it out, just in case. Again, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, @Waldorf99 was looking to have a second worksheet that would automatically show a filtered list from the first sheet. I can think of a few ways to do this (array formulas or pivot tables come to mind). The problem with mixing dynamic columns with static values is that the static values would become desynced from the dynamic ones.

In the original example, rows may have a blank value in the condition column in sheet one, and then may be assigned a Y or N at a later date. If a Y is assigned to a row in the middle of other rows, the filtered sheet would shift the existing rows down to make room. The static values would stay where they were, and would become desynced. To demonstrate:

[image: before edit in sheet 1]

If the above image is the original state of sheet 1 and 2...

[image: after edit in sheet 1]

...adding a y next to x.1.c would result in sheet two shifting columns A and B of row 2 down, but leaves columns C and D behind (as they are static, and not tied into the first two columns in any way).

One thing that may work as you are wanting are filters. You would only have one sheet, with all of the data manually entered. Then you can add filters, and change them to hide rows temporarily when needed.

To add and use filters:

[image: Step 1]

1. Start with your data all on one sheet...

[image: Step 2]

2. Highlight your data...

[image: Step 3]

3. On the Home tab, select "Format as Table" and choose any style...

[image: Step 4]

This turns your data into a table. You can filter by clicking the drop down in a given columns header row, then deselecting the values you want to hide.

[image: Results]

The results are a table that only shows the rows with a 'Y'.

The other rows aren't removed, just hidden. You can always reset or change your filters, to configure which rows are visible.

Note: when working with tables, they will auto expand to account for new rows, so long as you work in the row directly under the table (e.g. don't leave blank rows). You can also manually resize the table at any time by clicking and dragging from the bottom right corner of the table.

There are tons of resources of Excel tables online, and it's a pretty useful tool in Excel.

Hope that achieves what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! This has  worked brilliantly the way that I had wanted